# move 3d cursor if i have enabled select with right click

Tags: 3d-cursor

I want to move 3d cursor using shift + right click but i have enabled select with right click instead of left click. i don't want to use cursor tool
is there any way to move cursor without using cursor tool or enabling selection with left click?

thank you for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Preferences* where you enabled selecting with right-click, there is an option called *Alt Cursor Access*. If you enable it, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to place the 3D cursor.

[image: alt cursor access]